# How to automatically add extension to files in Maven with Ant plugin

Tags: maven, ant, maven-antrun-plugin

I have a Maven project that get a zip file and extracts it with the `maven-antrun-plugin`. The zip file contains a folder that contains xml files. However the `.xml` extension is missing in all files.
I want to tell Maven to rename each file like so `x -> x.xml`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already using the `maven-antrun-plugin`, you can do this with the [`move`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/move.html) task of Ant.

```
<move todir="my/src/dir" includeemptydirs="false">
  <fileset dir="my/src/dir">
    <exclude name="**/*.xml"/>
  </fileset>
  <mapper type="glob" from="*" to="*.xml"/>
</move>
```

This will rename every file in the directory `my/src/dir`, adding a `.xml` extension, only if it is not already present.